# How to connect to RDS from locally created django?

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to Aurora on RDS from a local Django application.

Docker is used as the execution environment.

Publicly Accessible is allowed to connect to RDS from local.

I have confirmed that I can connect from local with mysql command, but not from on django.

Why can't I connect from Django?

Commands tried:

```
$ mysql -h xxxx.xxxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -p
mysql>
```

This command allows you to get inside mysql.

The django database setup is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Output error statement:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxx.xxxxx.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.' (111)")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to just use everything in just one link using dj_database_url
the link should have just all credintials in it like so
postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DATABASE_NAME
you can put it in .env vars file or use it directly as you wish

```
    DATABASES = {
    "default": {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'HOST': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DB_URL")),
    },
}
```